# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined React API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api

I'm trying to build a products page with list of products with their details fetched from an external API and being displayed as cards. I looked through how to do it and found this to be similar to what I wanted to do but I mimicked the code in this post [React fetch api data to component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981004/react-fetch-api-data-to-component) and I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

**Products component**

```
class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    };
    componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=xxxxxxxx&page=1")
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: resp.results
            })
            console.log(this.state.items)      
    })};

   
      render() {
        var {isLoaded, items} = this.state;
        
        return (
            <div>
                {items.map(item => (<Card key={item.id} item={item} />))};
            </div>
        );
    }
  
}

export default Products;
```

**Card Component**

```
const Card = (props) => {
    const { item } = props;
    return (
        <div className="movie-container">
            <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{items.poster_path}" alt="NO PHOTO" className="movie-container__img" />
            <div className="movie-container__about">
                <span className="movie-container__percent">{item.vote_average}</span>
                <h2 className="movie-container__title">{item.original_title}</h2>
                <p className="movie-container__date">{item.release_date}</p>
                <p className="movie-container__text">{item.overview}</p>
                <a href="https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/" className="movie-container__more">MORE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: `items` is undefined, likely because `resp.results` is undefined.

Comment: what should I set the items to then?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if `render()` executes, `state.items` can be null or undefined, most likely *as a result of what your API returns, or how you process what it returns*.

The reason to 'blame' the API is because you initialize `items` to `[]` in the constructor, so initially there *is* an array and calling `map` will work.

To fix this, check if **`items`** has a value; if not then don't show anything. And then check if you access the API correctly, perhaps also dive into the API to see what it does and fix it.

It would also be good to check **`isLoaded`** so you don't show data unless the API call has finished.

```
render() {
    var {isLoaded, items} = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded || !items)
        return null; // or if you like, show a "Waiting" indicator

    return (
        <div>
            {items.map(item => (<Card key={item.id} item={item} />))};
        </div>
    );
}
```